# using IN(or similar) condition in an azure storage query

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have an object of type **Person** which has only two properties: **Name** and **Place**. I have an azure table of the same name with the same two columns and an additional column called **Date**. I have to fetch **date** based on condition that either the name **or** place exist in table.I have seperate lists for name and place from wherein it should match the value. For example:

```
//some data into these lists
    List<string> nameList = new List<string>(); 
    List<string> placeList = new List<string>();
```

After some research, I have tried something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Person> query = (from p in table.CreateQuery<Person>() where nameList .Contains(p.Name)|| placeList .Contains(p.Place)  select p);
```

But this gives an error saying not supported. What would be the best way to achieve this? Please note the name and place list can contain 1000s of entries.

**Update**

This is the error message :

```
The expression (value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]).Contains([10007].Name) Or
value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]).Contains([10007].Place)) is not supported.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out. I used the **GenerateFilterCondition** and the **CombineFilters** to achieve it.

Code:

```
    string queryString = String.Empty;
    string query1 = null;
    for(int i=0;i<nameList.Count;i++)
     {
      queryString  = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Name",QueryComparisons.Equal,nameList[i].ToString());
     if (i == 0)
      query1 = queryString;
      else
      query1 = TableQuery.CombineFilters(query1, TableOperators.Or, queryString);
      }
   queryString = string.Empty;
   for (int j = 0; j < placeList.Count;j++ )
     {
      queryString = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Place", QueryComparisons.Equal, placeList[j].ToString());
    query1 = TableQuery.CombineFilters(query1, TableOperators.Or, queryString);
    }
    TableQuery<Person> tblQuery = new TableQuery<Person>().Where(query1);
    List<Person> evntHst = table.ExecuteQuery(tblQuery).OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).ToList();
```

Hope it helps others! Cheers!!